# Why does Visible='<%#false%>' work on a GridView but not label?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, label, visible

I am scratching my head over this, but have no idea what the problem is. 
My actual code is

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="abc"
           Visible='<%#Request.QueryString["ListName"] == null %>' />
<asp:GridView ID="gvLists" runat="server"
              Visible='<%#Request.QueryString["ListName"] == null %>' />
```

As you can see, i am trying to only make the visibility of the object be driven by the querystring. It works fine for the GridView, but doesn't work for a label. I also tried Panel and HyperLink with the same results.

I am sure I could get this working by putting my code in the code-behind, but it won't be as clean.

Comment: I've a feeling that the `<%# %>` will only be evaluated on databinding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Alison for pointing me in the right direction. 
I needed to add `Page.DataBind()` to my Page_Load event in order for the expression to be evaluated.

Answer (score 5):

<%# %> works only on databound items.

you need to change it to <%= %> (Notice the "=")

Comment: While this didn't work, you did point me in the right direction

Comment: That won't work, because Visible is a server-side property and `<%= %>` only adds html to render to the client.

Answer (score 1):

<%= is uses to print to the page directly and the <%# is used for data binding elements. [Here](http://naspinski.net/post/inline-aspnet-tags-sorting-them-all-out-(3c25242c-3c253d2c-3c252c-3c252c-etc).aspx) is a great explanation of all the inline code directives.